# What is causing this Eclipse exception after my JUnit Plugin Test completes?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-rcp

I have a simple test which I run as a JUnit Plugin Test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {

  @Test
  public void doNothingTest(){
    System.out.println("Nothing to see here...");
  }

}
```

The test completes, then this is printed to the console:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core 2 1 2016-03-02 07:04:33.285
>       !MESSAGE AERI failed with an error. Please report this error: null ; version: 1.100.0.v20160211-1103
>       !STACK 0
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:217)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:90)
>         at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.SystemControl.executeHandler(SystemControl.java:103)
>         at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.SystemControl.isActive(SystemControl.java:65)
>         at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.util.LogListener.logging(LogListener.java:45)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:161)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:103)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:88)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:217)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:189)
>         at  ...

This continues for many, many lines.

Here's a snippet of the source from which the exception is thrown. The `Object result = ...` line throws an NPE.

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object object, Class<? extends Annotation> qualifier, PrimaryObjectSupplier objectSupplier) {
    Object result = invokeUsingClass(object, object.getClass(), qualifier, IInjector.NOT_A_VALUE, objectSupplier, null, true);
    if (result == IInjector.NOT_A_VALUE) {
        if (object != null && qualifier != null) {
            throw new InjectionException("Unable to find matching method to invoke. Searching for the annotation \"" + qualifier.toString() + "\" on an instance of \"" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\""); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
        }
        throw new InjectionException("Unable to find matching method to invoke. One of the arguments was null."); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    return result;
```

This source is from org.eclipse.e4.core.di.source_1.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar

- I'm running Eclipse Mars.
- JUnit Claims the Test Passed.
- I'm running with Java 1.8.
- My run configuration is set to clear the workspace. I
  updated Eclipse last week.
- The test above is part of a trivially simple plugin (New -> Plugin Project). This plugin is the only workspace plugin being deployed in the test configuration.

Comment: Does another Eclipse version work?

Comment: I recently upgrade from Luna to Mars. I did not see this behavior with Luna.

Comment: Create a bug report with a reproducable test case with Eclipse, and downgrade to Luna.

Comment: You need to show us the 'Caused by' part of the stack trace. The source you show is not really where the error occurs.

Comment: @greg-449 - I don't follow. It's a null pointer exception, not a wrapped exception. The top of the trace indicates the line where the error occurred. 

Here's the full trace: http://pastebin.com/kpM6AxHd

Comment: OK it is a different error from the one I was thinking about.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488868

Comment: The bug has been fixed and closed. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488868